# Renaming Tags via XSLT for Similar Tag Pattern

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have an xml as:

```
<FlightDetails1>
                    <CouponNumber1>1</CouponNumber1>
            <ServiceClass1>Y</ServiceClass1>
</FlightDetails1>
<FlightDetails2>
                        <CouponNumber2>2</CouponNumber2>
                        <ServiceClass2>Y</ServiceClass2>
</FlightDetails2>
<FlightDetails3>
                        <CouponNumber3></CouponNumber3>
                        <ServiceClass3>N</ServiceClass3>
</FlightDetails3>
```

Need to transform this xml to the below format:

```
<FlightDetails>
                        <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber>
            <ServiceClass>Y</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
<FlightDetails>
                        <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber>
                        <ServiceClass>Y</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
<FlightDetails>
                        <CouponNumber></CouponNumber>
                        <ServiceClass>N</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
```

Previously, when the tags were like `<FlightDetails> and <CouponNumber>`, I used the 'copy-of' function in the XSLT. With the tags being renamed, what is the simplest way to achieve that with an xslt?
XSLT:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
          <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:copy-of select="//FlightDetails1"/>
          </xsl:template>
```

Comment: " what is the simplest way to achieve that with an xslt? " The *simplest* way depends on what else is (or could be) in your XML. You don't always have to refer to elements by their name (or part of their name); sometimes it's more convenient to select nodes by their context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic version

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- the identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- elements whose names end with digits -->
  <xsl:template match="*[
     starts-with(name(), translate(name(), '01234567890', ''))
     and substring-after(name(), translate(name(), '01234567890', ''))
  ]">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(name(), '01234567890', '')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second template matches all elements that end in digits by...

1. removing all digits from the name

   ```
   translate(name(), '01234567890', '') := 'FlightDetails1' -> 'FlightDetails'
   ```
2. making sure it does not match elements with digits in the middle

   ```
   starts-with('FlightDetails1', 'FlightDetails')     := true
   starts-with('Flight1Details', 'FlightDetails')     := false
   ```
3. checking there is something after the start of the string (by definition this can only be one or more digits, all other elements already fail the previous test)

   ```
   substring-after('FlightDetails1', 'FlightDetails') := '1' (evaluates to true)
   ```

   This way the template matches any element with a name in the form `letters123`.
4. `<xsl:element name="{translate(name(), '01234567890', '')}">` then re-creates that element without the trailing digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the element names to persist, you can no longer use `copy` (or copy-of, the way you are using it).

Instead, match these elements in a separate template, for instance like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'FlightDetails')]">
  <xsl:element name="FlightDetails">
  <!--Further processing-->
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This template matches all forms of `FlightDetails` elements, that is to say, regardless of the number at the end of the element name. Then, with the `xsl:element` instruction you create a new element with the name "FlightDetails".

Then, go on to write similar templates for the other elements you wish to normalize. Note that now `apply-templates/` has come into play to leave it to the processor to decide which template to apply next.

A stylesheet that summarizes all this (I added a `root` element to your input XMl to make it well-formed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'FlightDetails')]">
  <xsl:element name="FlightDetails">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'CouponNumber')]">
  <xsl:element name="CouponNumber">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'ServiceClass')]">
  <xsl:element name="ServiceClass">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlightDetails>
  <CouponNumber>1</CouponNumber>
  <ServiceClass>Y</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
<FlightDetails>
  <CouponNumber>2</CouponNumber>
  <ServiceClass>Y</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
<FlightDetails>
  <CouponNumber/>
  <ServiceClass>N</ServiceClass>
</FlightDetails>
```

Comment: `<xsl:element name="ServiceClass">` is a very verbose way of stating `<ServiceClass>`. :)

Comment: I agree. But also, it shows clearly that the stylesheet generates new elements.

Comment: So does `<ServiceClass>`. ;) Every element you write in a template is a newly created one. Even `<xsl:copy>` creates all elements from scratch.

Comment: Please do not nit-pick on my choice of words. Of course you generate any element afresh, but to me the purpose is more obvious with `xsl:element` - even if it would have been more concise otherwise.

Comment: I used to do that, but I found that it wasn't always obvious at the end element (`</xsl:element>`) which element it was closing, which for large stylesheets can be very confusing. `</ServiceClass>` (in this instance) makes it much clearer.

Comment: I believe adding a comment would serve your purpose much better than superfluous code.

Comment: `<xsl:element name="fixedString">` is superfluous and an antipattern, it makes nothing clearer that would not have been clear from the start. It's like defending `<xsl:attribute name="foo"><xsl:value-of select="'bar'"></xsl:attribute>` because it "makes clear there's an attribute created". XSLT already is pretty verbose without things like that. (Also, there's no need to become angry at me. I'm suggesting improvements to code, that's what this whole site is about.)

Comment: No angriness intended. I acknowledge your arguments - in large templates it is indeed hard to guess which elements are being closed and it would have been better to write comments instead if something needed clarification.